# Alternative to GROUP BY to consolidate repeating values in single column

Tags: sql, db2

I'm using DB2 which apparently doesn't let you use the GROUP BY clause when it's returning more than one column. I have records that have repeating values for ID and name, for example:

```
EmpID  |  -   name  -   |  code  
___________________________________
111111    |    Williams   |   1 
---------------------------------   
111111    |    Williams   |   2   
----------------------------------
111112    |    Davis      |   3   
---------------------------------
111113    |    Gomez      |   1  
----------------------------------
111113    |    Gomez      |   3
----------------------------------
```

(Excuse my formatting) I need to get a single instance of each employee with a code (doesn't matter which code instance gets omitted as long as one shows up per employee).

Normally I could do:

```
SELECT * FROM employees GROUP BY EmpID;
```

DB2 doesn't let you do this for some reason. It says " The grouping is inconsistent." You can do:

```
SELECT EmpID from employees GROUP BY EmpID;
```

but if you introduce more return values then it gives you the error.

I tried looking into using a subquery and derived tables but I'm not sure how to compose it to select only one code value and exclude the records with a repeating employee value. If anyone has an answer or could point me to another thread that addresses this problem I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: So you normally use MySQL?

Comment: As pointed out below you do need an *alternative* to `GROUP BY`, you just need a proper use of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is required in most databases to `GROUP BY` each column in the `SELECT` list that is not in an aggregate function that is why you received an error message.

For your situation if it does not matter what `code` value is returned, then you can use an aggregate function and group by:

```
SELECT EmpID, name, MIN(code) code
FROM employees 
GROUP BY EmpID, name;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ccf0/1)

The group by is applied to both the `EmpId` and `name`, while the aggregate function is applied to the `code` column.

---

Note that due to that `EmpID` and `name` are functionally dependent on each other (as far as we can see from the sample you posted and the *"repeating values"* comment), the following two queries will return the same, identical results as the above query:

```
--- GROUP BY EmpID
------------------
SELECT EmpID, MIN(name) name, MIN(code) code
FROM employees 
GROUP BY EmpID; 


--- GROUP BY name
-----------------
SELECT MIN(EmpID) EmpID, name, MIN(code) code
FROM employees 
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I knew deep down I was doing something wrong. That makes perfect sense. Just to make sure I get it, if I added another functionally dependent column on the table such as lineID so that you could have repeating codes with a different lineID and you also want to disregard repeating lineID's you would do: 'select min(EmpID) EmpID, name, min(code) code, min(lineID) lineID group by name;', correct?

Comment: @rocklandcitizen Happy to help! You were definitely on the right track you just needed a little push in the right direction. :)

Comment: @rocklandcitizen Yes that is correct. Any columns that are in the select list need to be in either an aggregate function or a group by.

Comment: Thanks again. You saved me a lot of heart and head ache.